I want to update Xamarin application into .NET 8
I am very new Xamarin. I have a Xamarin native application for Android and iOS. I want to update it to .NET 8 but not migrate to MAUI. Is there any way I can do this? As i got to know it support till .net 6.0.
I tried to update the target framework and some NuGet packages. But getting project target error.

Have you checked this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/native-projects?view=net-maui-8.0
